# How can I change the color of the header on google chrome according to sections of the site?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have implemented on my Wordpress site with the following code:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#2189be">
```

I wanted to know if it would be possible to implement a different color depending on the category selected.

Comment: What does category selection means? Do you select from a dropdown? do you have many pages? do you have database behind data?

Comment: By category mean www.sito.it/android www.sito.it/widowsphone etc, certainly wordpress uses a database

Answer (score 0):

this is a jquery solution. (However it would be more standard saving colors in database and loading them using php):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url=window.location.href;
var category= url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //gets last part of url. you may change this algorithm if categories are not always in last part of url

if (category=="android"){
$('meta[name=theme-color]').attr('content', '#2189be');
}

if (category=="windowsphone"){
$('meta[name=theme-color]').attr('content', '#ff8800');
}

// etc.

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I include the jquery file function.php but not taken from the browser, you can opt for a solution php include in functions.php and call header.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Let me explain more precisely by entering this file in my theme bar does not change color

Comment: have you include jquery.js in your project before this function? can you test your project in PC and check if google chrome (javascript console) displays any error?

Comment: Google Chrome (JavaScript console) recognizes this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I solved this problem because I had forgotten to insert jQuery(document) but it returns the error Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined reported at line  var category= url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); @ali

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to define URL before trying to get its last part. I have updated answer b getting page URL in head of function.

Comment: Hi I updated the file jquery, the error no longer appears, but still does not work. maybe the problem and that the path ends with a slash? es www.sito.it/android/

Comment: Yes I think so. You can omit +1 from formula to get part before slash. A better way would be that you check if the length of category is greater than 0? if 0 then get previous part instead.